# Select from index structure

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Helo,
Sometimes I need to check only unique values on indexed column(s).
Is there any fast way to check this directly from index (clustered)?

I have table with several timestamps, each timestamp is in few milions rows, so even if I use index, query below takes quite long (5-8 minutes) with `Index Scan`.

```
select distinct TimeStamp from table
```

When I execute several times (for all values) query like this

```
Select top 1 TimeStamp from table where TimeStamp='2018-06-01 09:43:09.440'
```

it works instantly.

`Group by` didn't change anything

```
Select UpdateDate
from [z_Arch_Exp_Czesciowy]
group by UpdateDate
```

takes 6 minutes with index scan

Comment: I doubt indexing has any effect on distinct. Distinct is naturally going to be slow as all records must be checked... I am no expert in sql server, but perhaps a stored procedure might help (as I believe results can be cached by the server when possible)

Comment: On some occasions using group by instead of distinct is faster. You can't tell the engine how to access the data tho. If you already have a clustered index on that column and the query is as simple as you show here, then there's not much I can think of that you can do.

Comment: Define "quite long". How much does it is? Have you checked the execution plan to ensure it is performing an `INDEX SEEK` operation instead of, for example, `INDEX SCAN`?

Comment: It takes 5-8 minutes with `Index Scan`, but when I execute several (all values) queries `Select top 1 TimeStamp from table where TimeStamp=''2018-06-01 09:43:09.440'` it works instantly. Group by didn't change anything    `Select UpdateDate
from [z_Arch_Exp_Czesciowy]
group by UpdateDate` it takes 6 minutes with index scan

Comment: We need your index definition then. Could you post the create index?
I can guess your index is including too many columns and your TimeStamp isn't the first one in the index columns order.

Comment: Basically, an `INDEX SCAN` operation means your index isn't properly covering your query (or your query isn't properly coded in order to use index, point of views). Your target is to see an `INDEX SEEK` in your execution plan. In order to achieve that you must read some documentations about SQL Server performances.